# Огромное количество элементов в DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Проект на framework 4.0!

Внутри формы лежит DataGridView и ScrollBar. В DataGrid надо разместить большое количество элементов (8000 элементов).

Данные элементы загружаются асинхронно и первые 500 штук загружаются очень быстро, а далее всё медленнее и медленнее. Примерно после отметки 2000 элементов на DataGridView ощутимо падает скорость и производительность приложения.
Я включил двойную буферизацию, это значительно помогло.
Хотел ещё поставить виртуализацию, но код этого не позволил. (Придётся всё перелопатить, это *миллион часов съест из-за того, что проект старый и количество строчек кода соответствующее).

Насчёт кода: в коде данные хранятся уже в листе (8000 элементов), там соответствующий класс. В DataGridView они попадают по одной штуке немного откорректированные.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно, это дело оптимизировать!

Comment: 1.  Не использовать UI элемент, как место для хранения данных. 2. Виртуализация "код не позволит" - а от нас вы что тогда хотите, чтоб мы за вас этот код переписали, или что? Вы сами себе злобный буратино в этом случае, чтож поделать. 3. Пагинация, не грузите все, грузите частями, разбейте данные на страницы. 4. Динамичная загрузка, загрузили часть, проскролили ее до конца, загрузили еще часть, и так до тех пор, пока не загрузите все. 5. База, как бы банально это не звучало, очень редко пользователю нужны **все** данные на экране, а поиск и прочее работает отлично у БД.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ большое спасибо за ответ. Про "код не позволит" я имел введу, что мне не дадут времени, чтобы сидеть часами и рефакторить, чтобы реализовать виртуализацию (попробую конечно добиться этого, но реалии увы такие( сам понимаешь).  Я предполагаю, что проблема в том, что сборщик мусора при таком большом количестве элементов вызывается чаще и чаще, что и приводит к проблемам. Попробую взять на вооружение, что ты описал! Снова спасибо!

Comment: Сборщик мусора тут наверняка не при чём. / Хотелось бы увидеть хоть какой-то код.

Comment: _Проект на framework 4.0!_ - хорошо, что не 3.5, поднимите хотя-бы до 4.6.1, или вам Windows XP надо поддерживать? `BindingList<T>` используете, или только хардкор?

Comment: @aepot Подняться не сможем. Вы правы windows XP важен для проекта и в коде только хардкор.

Comment: _Физический_ размер контролов WinForms не может превышать 32768 пикселей (16 бит). Допустим, высота строки 20 пикселей, тогда высота 8000 строк составит 160 тысяч - это физически не может отобразиться. Как ни крути, а вам придётся использовать виртуальный режим грида.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov большое спасибо за ответ! Можете пожалуйста подсказать, где можно прочитать, что происходит, когда DataGridView выходит за этот диапазон или просто любой контрол.

Comment: 8000 строк для Grid - не так уж и много. Что-то еще делаете при отображении? Условное форматирование и пр. - вот реальный тормоз. Покажите голые строки и посмотрите производительность. Если все равно плохо - нужна пагинация.

Comment: Чтобы придать вопросу конструктива, нажен воспроизводимый пример, создайте пустой проект с нужной версией дотнета, занесите в него то что нужно и покажите в вопросе, чтобы отвечающий мог повторить проблему. Тогда и решение быстрее найдется.

Answer (score 1):

Решил я немного разобраться в этой теме, вспомнить подзабытые знания о WinForms.
Создал новый проект .NET Framework 4.8.
На форме в дизайнере пусто. ДатаГрид создаётся в коде, чтобы не было непонятностей и разночтений.
Шрифт по умолчанию.

Используем грид с включенной двойной буферизацией:

```
public class DoubleBufferedDataGridView : DataGridView
{
    protected override bool DoubleBuffered => true;
}
```

---

Сперва протестируем код, в котором размер грида увеличивается автоматически, по мере вставки в него строк. Для этого задаём `AutoSize = true`. А у родительского контрола (в данном случае - формы), задаём `AutoScroll = true`, чтобы можно было прокручивать её содержимое.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    DoubleBufferedDataGridView dataGridView;

    public Form1()
    {
        //InitializeComponent();            
        AutoScroll = true;

        dataGridView = new DoubleBufferedDataGridView
        {
            Parent = this,
            AutoSize = true
        };

        dataGridView.Columns.Add("Value", "Value");

        for (int i = 1; i <= 8000; i++)
            dataGridView.Rows.Add(new object[] { i });

        Text = dataGridView.Height.ToString();

        this.Load += Form1_Load;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Text += "  " + dataGridView.Height.ToString();
    }
}
```

В заголовок формы я сделал вывод размера грида. В конструкторе выводится *логический* размер, он считается до отрисовки (рендера) грида. А в событии `Load` выводится *физический* размер, уже после отрисовки. Эти значения равны 176080 и 65535.
В WinForms размер контролов ограничен значением 16 бит. Причём, насколько я помню, раньше это было `Int16.MaxValue` (32767). Видимо, позже переделали на `UInt.MaxValue`.
То есть 8000 строк никак не могут отобразится физически.

Однако, никаких тормозов я обнаружить не смог. 2978 строк, которые физически влезли в ограничение, выводятся мгновенно. Скролл формы работает плавно.
Правда, появляется ещё скролл грида, который глючит...

Как бы то ни было, такой способ вывода в корне неправилен. Поэтому рассмотрим другие.

---

Убираем `AutoSize` и `AutoScroll`.
Тестируем.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    DoubleBufferedDataGridView dataGridView;

    public Form1()
    {
        //InitializeComponent();

        dataGridView = new DoubleBufferedDataGridView
        {
            Parent = this,
            Dock = DockStyle.Left
        };

        dataGridView.Columns.Add("Value", "Value");

        for (int i = 1; i <= 8000; i++)
            dataGridView.Rows.Add(new object[] { i });
    }
}
```

Что тут может тормозить? Откровенно не понимаю.

---

Ещё один способ, с привязкой данных. Рекомендуемый.

Создаём класс модели, содержащий необходимые свойства:

```
public class Item
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

В коде используем коллекцию, которую привязываем (bind) к гриду. При этом нет необходимости создавать колонки вручную.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    DoubleBufferedDataGridView dataGridView;

    public Form1()
    {
        //InitializeComponent();            

        dataGridView = new DoubleBufferedDataGridView
        {
            Parent = this,
            Dock = DockStyle.Left
        };

        var list = new List<Item>();

        for (int i = 1; i <= 8000; i++)
            list.Add(new Item { Value = i });

        dataGridView.DataSource = list;
    }
}
```

Опять же, никаких тормозов, всё работает прекрасно.

---

Ни в одном из способов не была применена виртуализация грида. Даже без неё 8 тысяч строк он проглотил не поморщившись.

Вывод из этого такой: ищите причину падения скорости в своём коде.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Буду разбираться!